# Unresolved dependency [Class Service Layer]

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, light-inject

i using light inject in asp mvc .

using this code in global.asax in asp mvc .

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        var container = new ServiceContainer();
        container.RegisterControllers();
        container.RegisterControllers(typeof(Areas.Admin.AdminAreaRegistration).Assembly);
        container.Register<INewsService, NewsService>(new PerScopeLifetime());
        container.Register<ICategoryService, CategoryService>(new PerScopeLifetime());
        container.EnableMvc();
    }
```

and in controller :

```
private readonly INewsService _newsservice;
    private readonly ICategoryService _categoryservice;
    public AdminController(INewsService newsservice, ICategoryService categoryservice)
    {
        _newsservice = newsservice;
        _categoryservice = categoryservice;
    }
```

but it show me this error :

> > Unresolved dependency [Target Type: DA.Service.Service.NewsService], [Parameter: Repository(DA.Data.Repository.Repository`1[DA.Data.Domain.News])], [Requested dependency: ServiceType:DA.Data.Repository.Repository`1[DA.Data.Domain.News], ServiceName:]

whats the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you need to tell Unity what is the implementation of `DA.Data.Domain.News`.

`NewsService` depends on `News` and it cannot be implicitly resolved (either not found, or itself has some dependencies).

Also, you are using Unity in MVC wrongly. Use the Unity for MVC NuGet.

Comment: The way except using untity there is to solve this problem?

Comment: "The way except using untity there is to solve this problem?" ... what?

Comment: Using Unity is fine. But you don't usually do the service registration in the Application Start method. This leads me to believe you didn't use the correct NuGet. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.Mvc4/

Comment: @HristoYankov - The question is tagged `light-inject`, why would you assume the OP is using Unity?

Comment: The application startup path is the appropriate place to put the composition root in MVC. The `Unity.Mvc4` package just uses some "magic" to move the code to a different place, but the effect is exactly the same as putting the code here.

Answer (score 0):

The error states that your INewsService and ICategoryService both have dependencies (repositories) that are not registered with the container. You need to register the entire object graph. I would expect your registration to look something like:

```
    var container = new ServiceContainer();
    container.RegisterControllers();
    container.RegisterControllers(typeof(Areas.Admin.AdminAreaRegistration).Assembly);
    container.Register<INewsService, NewsService>(new PerScopeLifetime());
    container.Register<IRepository<News>, Repository<News>>(new PerRequestLifetime());
    container.Register<ICategoryService, CategoryService>(new PerScopeLifetime());
    container.Register<IRepository<Category>, Repository<Category>>(new PerRequestLifetime());
    container.EnableMvc();
```

Comment: Edit your question and post the error message you are now getting (as text, not as an image).

Comment: Apparently, you are injecting the concrete repository into your services instead of an abstraction. Change your services to accept `IRepository<T>` instead of `Repository<T>` and the above code will work.